# Python : receive variable name as input ,stored in another file

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a scenario, where I need to get the vale of a variable stored in another file based on the input received, for example, here file1.py contains several sql stored in each variable, file2.py has to receive the variable name stored in file1.py as a input.

I have to call file2.py from another program, from where the input will be passed.
When I pass the variable name(--receive_input "v_sql1") directly as a input, the program takes that as a string and errors out. Is there any way I can pass the variable name(v_sql1) and the program can still point that to the actual variable and get the SQL?

```
file1.py
v_sql1 = " select * from table"
v_sql2 = "select * from table2"

file2.py
from file1 import *
df = spark.sql(receive_input)
```

Comment: `df.spark.sql(v_sql1)` should work just fine.  Now, if you want to specify "v_sql1" as a string, that doesn't work.  You'd need to use a dictionary.

Comment: file2.py has to be called from another program, each time I call the program, I pass a different input to file2.py.

Comment: What I don't understand is where `receive_input` is defined. I am trying to connect, but are `v_sql1` and `v_sql2` used anywhere? It may just be a matter of importing it locally with a different name. Something along the lines of `from file1 import v_sql1 as receive_input`

Comment: I call file2.py from an another program, from there I pass the input. example: calling_program.py file2.py --receive_input "v_sql1"

Comment: @TimRoberts solution works, I'm wondering whether it's possible to get that when the SQL's are assigned to a variable. In actual implementation, the SQL's are quiet complex. where I use some formatting like this f"select * from {table_name}", wondering it will work inside dictionary

Comment: f-strings are evaluated when they are found, but you can use `"select * from {table_name}"` and then use `sqlstmts[pick].format(table_name=my_table)`.

Comment: The problem with this "sqlstmts[pick].format(table_name=my_table)" is, The sql's are picked dynamically from the calling script, So I won't be knowing what tables to include in the .format(table_name=my_table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're after.

```
file1.py

sqlstmts = {
  'v_sql1': "select * from table",
  'v_sql2': "select * from table2"
}

file2.py

import file1
pick = "v_sql1"
df = spark.sql(file1.sqlstmts[pick])
```

Comment: I missed a point in my question earlier, I have updated it now. file2.py has to be called from another program, where I will be passing different input every time.

Comment: That doesn't change anything.  Whatever method you use to get the string in there, just look it up in the dictionary.

Comment: Great, It works when I defined it as a dictionary. Thanks. But, Is it possible to get the SQL's, when they are defined as a variable, like I mentioned in the question?

Comment: Not by variable name.  That's just not the right way to do it.